# Covert Old Dovecot Configuration to New Format

Tags: postfix, dovecot, mailbox

I am trying to setup a very simple mail server with virtual domains with Postfix and Dovecot. I was following this steps to setup the postfix and first part it worked fine.

https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_postfix_virtual_hosting

Then i moved to the next part

https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_postfix_virtual_hosting_2

this gives me errors in the configuration file format as follows

```
[root@Clients info]# service dovecot restart
Stopping Dovecot Imap:                                     [  OK  ]
Starting Dovecot Imap: doveconf: Warning: NOTE: You can get a new clean config file with: doveconf -n > dovecot-new.conf
doveconf: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:2: protocols=imaps is no longer necessary, remove it
doveconf: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:2: protocols=pop3s is no longer necessary, remove it
doveconf: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:3: ssl_disable has been renamed to ssl
doveconf: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:4:
```

then corrected the above errors but still gives me following

```
[root@Clients info]# service dovecot restart
Stopping Dovecot Imap:                                     [FAILED]
Starting Dovecot Imap: doveconf: Warning: NOTE: You can get a new clean config file with: doveconf -n > dovecot-new.conf
doveconf: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:10: login_dir has been removed
doveconf: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:11: login_chroot has been replaced by service { chroot }
doveconf: Fatal: Error in configuration file /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf line 12: Unknown setting: login
```

I dont know how to fix this issues, my

1. dovecot version is

   ```
   [root@Clients info]# dovecot --version
   2.0.9
   ```
2. Postfix version is

   ```
   [root@Clients info]# postconf -d | grep mail_version
   mail_version = 2.6.6
   milter_macro_v = $mail_name $mail_version
   ```

My Dovecot configuration is

```
base_dir = /var/run/dovecot/
protocols = imap pop3
ssl = no
ssl_cert = /etc/ssl/server.crt
ssl_key = /etc/ssl/server.key
ssl_parameters_file = /var/run/dovecot/ssl-parameters.dat
ssl_parameters_regenerate = 24
log_path = /var/log/dovecot
info_log_path = /var/log/dovecot.info
login_dir = /var/run/dovecot/login
login_chroot = yes
login = imap
login_executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/imap-login
login_user = dovecot
login = pop3
login_executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/pop3-login
verbose_ssl = yes
valid_chroot_dirs = /var/spool/vmail
default_mail_env = maildir:/var/spool/vmail/%d/%n
imap_executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/imap
pop3_executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/pop3
auth = default
auth_mechanisms = plain digest-md5
auth_userdb = passwd-file /etc/dovecot/users
auth_passdb = passwd-file /etc/dovecot/passwd
auth_executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-auth
auth_user = root
auth_verbose = yes
```

And when tried to create new conf as instrcuted

```
[root@Clients ~]#  doveconf -n > dovecot-new.conf
doveconf: Warning: NOTE: You can get a new clean config file with: doveconf -n > dovecot-new.conf
doveconf: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:10: login_dir has been removed
doveconf: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:11: login_chroot has been replaced by service { chroot }
doveconf: Fatal: Error in configuration file /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf line 12: Unknown setting: login
```

Can someone please point me how to fix this issues ?

Comment: Have you tried running `dovecot -n`, as it suggests?

Comment: @MadHatter i have updated the question  with that output as well.